# android How to deactivate an app from taskmanager

Tags: android, taskmanager

My app has an Alarm Manager, so I suppose that it is still active on Task Manager. Is there any way to deactivate the App from TaskManager while alarm is sleeping?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Taziano

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Android will automatically kill your process and remove it from the task list when it finds it necessary to free up memory space.

Comment: Somebody claimed that the app appears in task manager all the time!

Comment: It could remain in there for quite some time. That being said, its not really anything to worry about and something all apps will contend with. So, while there are ways to remove it, don't worry about it and let Android handle it.